# Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime

Tags: c#, linux, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, mono

I am trying to run my console application on linux machine using mono  , application was running but it stop by showing error on console

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application

please help me to come out from this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your mono version. Also see if using `--arch=32` flag will work, if it is a 32bit binary.